# Cannot import gym_wrapper for ACME, any solution?

Tags: python, python-3.x, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, acme

**Import of acme is successfull, but not able to find gym wrapper class**

```
import acme
from acme.wrappers import gym_wrapper
```

**Error Message while running**

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
\<ipython-input-4-9d5212a1080d\> in \<module\>()
1 # reinforcement learning
2 import acme
\----\> 3 from acme.wrappers import gym_wrapper
4 from acme.environment_loop import EnvironmentLoop
5 from acme.utils.loggers import TerminalLogger, InMemoryLogger

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'acme.wrappers'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.
```

**Any alternative api for gym_wrapper in ACME framework?**

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to install dm-acme environment module.
It's clearly stated in the section 3. of installation process

```
pip install dm-acme[envs]
```